# How to control the up order of network interfaces?

Tags: networking, interface, network-bridge, routing, network-bonding

I have /etc/network/interfaces as follow. Every time the system boots up, the route is wrong so the gateway is not reachable. I'd have to ifdown br0 && ifup br0 to fix the route table and make everything work. How to fix this forever?

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet manual
bond-master bond0

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet manual
bond-master bond0

auto bond0
iface bond0 inet dhcp
 bond-mode balance-tlb
 bond-slaves none

auto br0
iface br0 inet dhcp
 bridge_ports bond0
```

*Edit*

This is the route table from `ip r s` after I reboot the host. There is an extra routing path.

Before restart br0:

```
default via 10.69.208.129 dev bond0  metric 100 
10.69.208.128/26 dev bond0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.69.208.172 
10.69.208.128/26 dev br0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.69.208.172 
169.254.0.0/16 dev br0  scope link  metric 1000 
192.168.1.0/24 dev lxcbr0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.1
```

After restart br0:

```
default via 10.69.208.129 dev br0  metric 100 
10.69.208.128/26 dev br0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.69.208.172 
169.254.0.0/16 dev br0  scope link  metric 1000 
192.168.1.0/24 dev lxcbr0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.1
```

Comment: If your `/etc/network/interfaces` file is correct according to the [documentation for ifenslave](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/saucy/ifenslave-2.6/saucy/view/head:/debian/README.Debian) as well as the [documentation for bridge-utils](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/en/man5/bridge-utils-interfaces.5.html) then I think it's a "race condition" bug if the interfaces do not come up in the correct order. If there is a mistake in your `interfaces` file then hopefully someone will be able to provide details in an answer here.

Comment: So I don't think "how do I adjust the order?" is really the right way to phrase your question. It's more "why is there a race condition here?"

Comment: Should I set bond0 as manual instead of dhcp? I will try next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing bond0 to manual instead of dhcp, now it works.

Answer (score 0):

you need to put script to up/down interface to your `/etc/network/interface` file

ubuntu is debian and this should helps you

[Click here for Debian Networking Configuration](http://wiki.debian.org/NetworkConfiguration)

Bringing up an interface without an IP address

To create a network interface without an IP address at all use the manual method and use pre-up and post-down commands to bring the interface up and down.

```
   iface eth0 inet manual
      pre-up ifconfig $IFACE up
      post-down ifconfig $IFACE down
```